# What does the error info means?

Tags: java

```
package example;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.lang.Object;

class Utils {
    public static Object copy(Object oldObj) {
        Object obj = null;
        try {
            // Write the object out to a byte array
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            out.writeObject(oldObj);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            // Retrieve an input stream from the byte array and read
            // a copy of the object back in.
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            obj = in.readObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();   
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            cnfe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return obj;
    }
}

public class mytest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Object clonedObject = Utils.copy(new Object());
        clonedObject.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Above code is to show how deep copy works by changing a object to byte array. But myeclipse gives below error messages and I don't know why.

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.Object
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1156)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:326)
    at example.Utils.copy(mytest.java:17)
    at example.mytest.main(mytest.java:37)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at example.mytest.main(mytest.java:38)
```

Could you please help? Thanks!

Comment: does your object implement serializable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What causes a NotSerializableException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893833/what-causes-a-notserializableexception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to serialize not `Serializable` (that is, it doesn't implement the interface `Serializable`) object

try this :

```
Object clonedObject = Utils.copy(new String("Hello");
```

`String` class is `Serializable`

Answer (score 1):

Your Object should implement [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface

**HINT:** For clone the object, far better to implement [`Cloneable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) interface and use the `object.clone()` method

Comment: clone() performs deep copy or shadow copy?

Comment: Shallow, by default. But you can override it as well.

Answer (score 1):

It means that `java.lang.Object` is not serializable, it doesn't implement `Serializable`, probably you are passing an object of class `Object` to your method.

Answer (score 1):

When you do writeObject, the objevt you write needs to be Serializable. Try to change the signature of your `copy`-method to

```
public static Object copy(Serializable oldObj)
```

The error message will be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The `Object` class does not implement the `Serializable` interface, so it cannot be used directly with object streams. More details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html).

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject%28java.lang.Object%29) of `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject`:

> Throws:
>
> NotSerializableException - Some object to be serialized does not implement the java.io.Serializable interface.

This makes sense, because you call your method with the parameter `new Object()`. Indeed, `Object` does not implement `Serializable`. I wonder, however, why the signature of `writeObject` isn't simply

```
writeObject(Serializable object)
```

which would prevent this kind of errors.

Comment: This is one of java's retrofitting dinosaurs. Another one is the Cloneable-interface and its implementation in Object!

Answer (score 0):

It is saying that your object is not eligible for *Serialization process* because it is not implemented `Serilizable` interface.
According to java [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/NotSerializableException.html)

> `java.io.NotSerializableException` Thrown when an instance is required to have a Serializable interface. The serialization runtime or the class of the instance can throw this exception.